# Comparing views using join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have to compare 6 views. Each view consists of 3 columns, `Table_Name`, `Column_Name`, `Country`. 
Sample:

```
view1:
Table_Name  Column_Name    Country
TML_Daily   LineID         CH
TML_Daily   LineOrder      CH
TML_Daily   LineName       CH
TML_Daily   LineName_GER   CH
TML_Daily   LineName_ITA   CH
TML_Daily   LineName_FRA   CH
TML_Daily   LineLevel      CH

view2:
Table_Name  Column_Name    Country
TML_Daily   LineID         FR
TML_Daily   LineOrder      FR
TML_Daily   LineName       FR
TML_Daily   LineName_GER   FR
TML_Daily   LineName_RUS   FR
TML_Daily   LineLevel      FR

view3:
Table_Name  Column_Name    Country
TML_Daily   LineID         AU
TML_Daily   LineOrder      AU
TML_Daily   LineName       AU
TML_Daily   LineName_GER   AU
TML_Daily   LineName_FRA   AU
TML_Daily   LineLevel      AU
```

As you can see, `view2` is missing two lines compared to `view1`, but has additional line, which isn't present in the other views. Also `view2`is missing one line.

In each view, there is data of tables and columns from each database.
Here is what I want: I want to compare views, so I could see all tables with its columns from across all views. Then it should use some marker column, which is indicator if column is or isn't present in the view.

Example basing on sample data:

```
Table:      Column:       CH    FR    AU
TML_Daily   LineID        1     1     1
TML_Daily   LineOrder     1     1     1
TML_Daily   LineName      1     1     1
TML_Daily   LineName_GER  1     1     1
TML_Daily   LineName_ITA  1     0     0
TML_Daily   LineName_FRA  1     0     1
TML_Daily   LineName_RUS  0     1     0
TML_Daily   LineLevel     1     1     1
```

This is my query so far, but it does not work as I expected at all, because it does something like a cross join.

```
SELECT distinct
            COALESCE(c.Table_Name, a.Table_Name, l.Table_Name) AS TableName,
            COALESCE(c.Column_Name, a.Column_Name, l.Column_Name) AS ColumnName,
            ISNULL(c.Column_Name, 0) AS CH,
            ISNULL(a.Column_Name, 0) AS AU,
            ISNULL(l.Column_Name, 0) AS FR
FROM DB1.dbo.v_TECH_ColumnList c
FULL OUTER JOIN DB2.dbo.v_TECH_ColumnList a
ON a.Table_Name=c.Table_Name
FULL OUTER JOIN DB3.dbo.v_TECH_ColumnList l
ON l.Table_Name=c.Table_Name
ORDER BY TableName, ColumnName
```

Please let me know if something isn't clear.

Comment: Do the views have more table names (`Table_Name`) in them than `TML_Daily`?

Comment: Another question, are the column names (`Column_Name`) a fixed set of columns? Are they stored in column table somewhere?

Comment: @TT. First question: yes, each views has around 50 different table names. Some of them got more, some less.
Second question: Columns are stored in those views only. Number of columns is not fixed. Some tables got even 20 columns since they are a fact tables, and some got only 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this does what you want.

```
DECLARE @v1 TABLE(table_name VARCHAR(32),column_name VARCHAR(32),country VARCHAR(3));
INSERT INTO @v1(table_name,column_name,country)VALUES
    ('TML_Daily','LineID','CH'),
    ('TML_Daily','LineOrder','CH'),
    ('TML_Daily','LineName','CH'),
    ('TML_Daily','LineName_GER','CH'),
    ('TML_Daily','LineName_ITA','CH'),
    ('TML_Daily','LineName_FRA','CH'),
    ('TML_Daily','LineLevel','CH');

DECLARE @v2 TABLE(table_name VARCHAR(32),column_name VARCHAR(32),country VARCHAR(3));
INSERT INTO @v2(table_name,column_name,country)VALUES
    ('TML_Daily','LineID','FR'),
    ('TML_Daily','LineOrder','FR'),
    ('TML_Daily','LineName','FR'),
    ('TML_Daily','LineName_GER','FR'),
    ('TML_Daily','LineName_RUS','FR'),
    ('TML_Daily','LineLevel','FR');

DECLARE @v3 TABLE(table_name VARCHAR(32),column_name VARCHAR(32),country VARCHAR(3));
INSERT INTO @v3(table_name,column_name,country)VALUES
    ('TML_Daily','LineID','AU'),
    ('TML_Daily','LineOrder','AU'),
    ('TML_Daily','LineName','AU'),
    ('TML_Daily','LineName_GER','AU'),
    ('TML_Daily','LineName_FRA','AU'),
    ('TML_Daily','LineLevel','AU');

SELECT
    tc.table_name,
    tc.column_name
INTO
    #table_columns
FROM
    (
        SELECT table_name,column_name FROM @v1
        UNION 
        SELECT table_name,column_name FROM @v2
        UNION 
        SELECT table_name,column_name FROM @v3
    ) AS tc;

SELECT
    tc.table_name,
    tc.column_name,
    CASE WHEN v1.country IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS CH,
    CASE WHEN v2.country IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS FR,
    CASE WHEN v3.country IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS AU
FROM
    #table_columns AS tc
    LEFT JOIN @v1 AS v1 ON v1.table_name=tc.table_name AND v1.column_name=tc.column_name
    LEFT JOIN @v2 AS v2 ON v2.table_name=tc.table_name AND v2.column_name=tc.column_name
    LEFT JOIN @v3 AS v3 ON v3.table_name=tc.table_name AND v3.column_name=tc.column_name
ORDER BY
    tc.table_name,
    tc.column_name;

DROP TABLE #table_columns;
```

---

The output is the following:

```
+------------+--------------+----+----+----+
| table_name | column_name  | CH | FR | AU |
+------------+--------------+----+----+----+
| TML_Daily  | LineID       |  1 |  1 |  1 |
| TML_Daily  | LineLevel    |  1 |  1 |  1 |
| TML_Daily  | LineName     |  1 |  1 |  1 |
| TML_Daily  | LineName_FRA |  1 |  0 |  1 |
| TML_Daily  | LineName_GER |  1 |  1 |  1 |
| TML_Daily  | LineName_ITA |  1 |  0 |  0 |
| TML_Daily  | LineName_RUS |  0 |  1 |  0 |
| TML_Daily  | LineOrder    |  1 |  1 |  1 |
+------------+--------------+----+----+----+
```

Comment: This works, but partially. It combines every single table with all available columns, so when I compare only 3 views now, it's like 66k rows.

Comment: @Dodzik I based my answer on your question *"I want to compare views, so I could see **all tables** and **all columns** from across **all views**"*. That is why you're getting so many rows. So I'm not entirely sure what it is you want... Do you want to base your comparison from just a single view and start from there? That correct?

Comment: Ah, I see it now. I made a mistake. I don't want to see all columns, but only those, which belongs to their tables.
I don't want to base comparison on single view, because column and table numbers may vary between views.

Comment: @Dodzik Let me review my script. I'll update it shortly.

Comment: @Dodzik Updated. I rewrote using TABLE variables to test on my SQL Server instance. You can surely modify it to your specific tables. Note that the temporary table is not strictly necessary, you can rewrite it as a derived table instead.

Comment: Works like a charm, tank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is feature of full outer join that combines your data from "left" and "right" table for every join.
If u want to check wheter something is or not included keyword "exists"/"not exists" with unions (exclude then country from query) should be more efficient.
tj